# Proof that Component-wise MH algorithm is invariant w.r.t. target measure

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains, simulation

consider a standard situation in Bayesian modelling,
given real vector parameter $\theta=(\theta_1,\dotsc,\theta_n)$ and observations $x$ we derive a posterior distribution $\pi$ with posterior density $f(\theta|x)$ with respect to some measure (without loss of generality we might consider Lebesgue measure on Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Let's assume we are interested in generating samples from posterior density/distribution. The standard approach is to use Metropolis Hastings algorithm with some appropriately chosen proposal density $q(\theta^*|\theta)$. The resulting Markov chain constructed from MH algorithm  (if $q$ satisfies some conditions) is ergodic and invariant with respect to $\pi$ (the proof can be found in many sources).

I'm interested in another approach, where I want to sample and accept or reject each component of $\theta$ separately in cycles, instead of generating and accepting or rejecting the whole $\theta$ at once. So in each iteration of such an algorithm:

1. sample $\theta_1$ from $q_1(\theta_1^*|\theta_1)$ and accept or reject it based on acceptance probability $\alpha_1$,
2. sample $\theta_2$ from $q_2(\theta_2^*|\theta_2)$ and accept or reject it based on acceptance probability $\alpha_2$,
3. ...
4. sample $\theta_n$ from $q_n(\theta_n^*|\theta_n)$ and accept or reject it based on acceptance probability $\alpha_n$,

assuming $q_i$ and $\alpha_i$ are correctly defined.

This algorithm is sometimes called Component-wise Metropolis Hastings algorithm. The standard argument of proving the resulting chain of such an algorithm is ergodic and invariant with respect to $\pi$ is that the composition kernel defined as
$$P=P_1\circ P_2 \circ \dots \circ P_n,$$
where $P_i$ is invariant with respect to $\pi$ is also $\pi$-invariant. However, I don't see how the Markov kernels constructed for each $\theta_i$ are invariant with respect to whole posterior distribution. We are generating only one sample each time, $q_i$ is one-dimensional, the argument doesn't make sense to me. Even if we consider $q_i$ to be $n$-dimensional by fixing other elements of $\theta$.

So I'm asking, do you have any clearly explained source proving that CWMH works? Or would anyone mind providing detailed analysis? Thanks in advance.